# OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture2D indexing

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, texture2d

I understand how `texture2D` works in general. My question is more specific.

In the code fragment:

```
  texture2D(sTexture, texCoord.st)
```

Are `texCoord.s` and `texCoord.t` between `[0, 1]`, or

Do they have a square size, or

Do they have the image size?

If they are not `[0, 1]`, what is the point of having the coordinates `s`, `t` to be floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texcoords are normalized floats (range [0,1]) in the normal case, and unnormalized floats (range [0,w] or [0,h], respecitvely) in the case of `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`.

The texcoords are never integer when sampling from it, but always floating point since not a specific texel is *fetched*, but the texture is *sampled* at some location, not just the texel centers. So during sampling, the texels define rectangluar patches in texture space, and the texture filter will define the sampling function to use define a resulting color for every location in the whole texture space. For example, `GL_LINEAR` will do a linear interpolation between neighboring texels if you sample inbetween their texel centers.

Comment: So if I am using GL_OES_EGL_image_external, then it should be in 0,1? It is hard to find such information online :). Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with that particular extension, but from briefly skimming over the extension spec, I think it should indeed be the ordinary [0,1] range for those textures.